# Python & SQLAlchemy many-to-many relation error after specify schema name

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Here the code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

AvailableModules = db.Table('available_modules',
    db.Column('customer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id')),
    db.Column('module_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modules.id')),
    schema='tcloud_admin')

class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"tcloud_admin"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....
    modules = db.relationship('Module', secondary=AvailableModules)

class Module(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modules'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"tcloud_admin"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....
```

Trying the above script gives me this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with
>   column 'available_modules.customer_id' could not find table
>   'customers' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Without specifying the schema name everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a custom schema name all foreign keys that reference a table or column in that schema must explicitly contain that schema name too.

Your `ForeignKey('customers.id')` references a different table `customers` which is not inside your custom schema. As this table does not exist at all you get the corresponding error.

To fix the error change the foreign keys:

```
db.ForeignKey('tcloud_admin.customers.id')
db.ForeignKey('tcloud_admin.modules.id')
```

This is also explained in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name)